# Storing and Grouping IP Addresses in CouchDB

Tags: couchdb

I have a Couch Database that contains a stack of IP address documents like this:

```
{
   "_id": "09eea172ea6537ad0bf58c92e5002199",
   "_rev": "1-67ad27f5ab008ad9644ce8ae003b1ec5",
   "1stOctet": "10",
   "2ndOctet": "1",
   "3rdOctet": "3",
   "4thOctet": "55"
}
```

The documents consist of multiple IP that are part of different subnet ranges.

I need a way to reduce/group these documents based on the 1st, 2nd, 3rd and 4th Octets in order to produce a reduced list of subnets.

Has anybody done anything like this before.

Best Regards,

Carlskii

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you're looking for, if you can provide more of an example as to your desired output, I can likely be of more help.

First, I would have your document structure look like this: (if you can't change that structure, it's not a big deal)

```
{
   "ip": "10.1.3.55"
}
```

Your map function would look like:

```
function (doc) {
    emit(doc.ip.split("."));
}
```

You'll need a reduce function, I've just used this in my testing

```
_count
```

Then I would use the `group_level` view query parameter to group based on each octet.

- 1 = group based on 1st octet
- 2 = group based on 1st-2nd octet
- 3 = group based on 1st-3rd octet
- 4 = group based on entire octet

`group=true` is functionally the same in this case as `group_level=4`

Comment: Thanks Dominic - I'll restructure my data and give this a try!